# How to get a particular value from a map

Tags: stack, blockchain, smartcontracts, clarity, clarity-lang

In my contract I have a map with a principal as its key and a tuple as its value. I want to get a particular value from the value-tuple for every principal in the map.
Let's say I want to get the salary for every member from the map below.
`(define-map members principal {position: (string-ascii 30), salary: uint})`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `map-get`

Check this examples

```
;; A map that creates a principal => uint relation.
(define-map balances principal uint)

;; Set the "balance" of the tx-sender to u500.
(map-set balances tx-sender u500)

;; Retrieve the balance.
(print (map-get? balances tx-sender))
```

Or

```
(define-map orders uint {maker: principal, amount: uint})

;; Set two orders.
(map-set orders u0 {maker: tx-sender, amount: u50})
(map-set orders u1 {maker: tx-sender, amount: u120})

;; retrieve order with ID u1.
(print (map-get? orders u1))
```

Comment: Yeah, this works but for just a particular ```key```. This case here is going all the ```keys``` that has been set to the ```map``` and get a particular value from the ```value-tuple```.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Clarity's `get` function in conjunction with `map-get`:

Example:

```
(define-map members principal {position: (string-ascii 30), salary: uint})

(map-set members 'ST3QFME3CANQFQNR86TYVKQYCFT7QX4PRXM1V9W6H {position: "test", salary: u500})

(print (get salary (map-get? members 'ST3QFME3CANQFQNR86TYVKQYCFT7QX4PRXM1V9W6H)))
```

And a link to Clarity's `get` function demonstrating this usage: https://docs.stacks.co/docs/write-smart-contracts/clarity-language/language-functions#get

However, you can't iterate through a map, you need to know the key to look up data, so if you wanted to iterate, you would need a list of all the principals and iterate through that using the `map` function, looking up the corresponding principal in the map on each iteration.